Typescript app has to clear browser cache and cookies after new deployment
We are deploying our TypeScript application on an Nginx server. After deploying new code, most new features work fine, but some modules are showing blank and not all changes are reflected in the browser. Users have to open an incognito window or clear their cache to see the updates.
Is there a way to automatically serve the latest changes to the end-user during the build time, so they don't have to clear their cache manually?

You have a classic browser cache management issue. Look for HTTP Caching for detailed explanations, e.g. on MDN.
Your React app is very probably bundled with webpack or Vite build engines, which generate "fingerprinted" JS files (their file names are made up of random looking alphanumeric characters, different for every build). This fingerprinting technique is designed to "bust" browser cache, irrespective of any Cache-Control policy implemented in your server.
However, this does not apply to the index.html file, which must keep this exact name. So you need to configure your Nginx server to serve this file with a proper Cache-Control HTTP header, so your users' browser will have to either revalidate it everytime (no-cache), or never cache it (no-store):

The no-cache response directive indicates that the response can be stored in caches, but the response must be validated with the origin server before each reuse [...]
If you want caches to always check for content updates while reusing stored content, no-cache is the directive to use. It does this by requiring caches to revalidate each request with the origin server.

